# Why Faulhaber's formula dosen't work for $p-1$ power sum on $\bmod p$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

From Faulhaber's formula, $\sum_{i=1}^{p-1}i^k$ is the multiple of $p$.
However, when $k=p-1$, from Fermat's little theorem, $\sum_{i=1}^{p-1}i^k=-1\bmod p$. So, my guess is wrong. What mistake did I make?

Comment: It's because of the $k+1$ in the denominator in the formula.

Comment: That might be the reason. How to prove it?

Comment: By using the generator $g$, we can show that $\sum_{i=1}^{p-1} i^k = \sum_{i=0}^{p-2} g^{ik} = (1-g^{k(p-1)})/(1-g^k)=0 \bmod p$ when $g^k \neq 1 \Leftrightarrow k\neq p-1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because denominator has $k+1$ factor in the formula.

For $k\neq p-1$, we can show that $\sum_{i=1}^{p-1}i^k = 0\bmod p$. 
By using the generator $g$, $\sum_{i=1}^{p-1} i^k = \sum_{i=0}^{p-2} g^{ik} = (1-g^{k(p-1)})/(1-g^k)=0 \bmod p$ when $g^k \neq 1 \Leftrightarrow k\neq p-1$.